# Google Cardboard Head Motion Tracking not working

Tags: google-cardboard

I changed google VR SDK to Cardboard SDK. I cannot experience the head motion as previously. Can anyone give me a solution to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change your phone too?
The device must have a gyro for the head motion tracking to work.